# onclick button redirect with variable on same page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

First off, I'm quite new to HTML, CSS and JS and I've spent a long time trying to figure something out that may be relatively basic, so I'd appreciate any advice (or a link to a similar question already asked).

I've been building a B2B website for my employer where each logged in client needs to be able to access different content on one specific navbar menu item. This menu button could lead to any of 5 different resources (PDF documents via a URL) depending on specific parameters unique to each client.

I've managed to create unique files that reference back to the DOM for each client dependent on their log-in credentials, however I am unable to embed this into the Menu button. On a side note, this website queries back to our SQL database.

Menu Bar:

```
 <ul style="">
             <li style="">
                <a class="menulinks currentItem" style="" href="xxx.aspx">
                    Agent Area
                </a>
              </li>         
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menuHeader " style="display:none;" href="xxy.aspx" aria-haspopup="true">
                    Bookings
                </a>
                
                 <ul>
                     
                     <li class="menulinks subItem" style="display:none;">
                      <a class="menulinks subItem " style="display:none;" href="xxxz.aspx">
                          Online Bookings</a>
                     </li>
                     
                     <li class="menulinks subItem" style="display:none;">
                      <a class="menulinks subItem " style="display:none;" href="xxxu.aspx?dummy=-1">
                          List Bookings</a>
                     </li>
                     
                     <li class="menulinks subItem disabled" style="display:none;">
                      <a class="menulinks subItem disabled " style="display:none;" href="javascript:confirmNewBooking('', 'zxcv.aspx')" onclick="javascript: return false;">
                          New Quote</a>
                     </li>
                     
                     <li class="menulinks subItem disabled" style="display:none;">
                      <a class="menulinks subItem disabled " style="display:none;" href="ViewBooking.aspx?bookingId=-1" onclick="javascript: return false;">
                          This Booking</a>
                     </li>
                     
                 </ul>
              
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menulinks " style="display:none;" href="yut.aspx">
                    Online Tariff
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menulinks " style="display:none;" href="PTF.aspx">
                    FIT Tariffs
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menulinks " style="display:none;" href="qwert.aspx">
                    Product Search
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menulinks " style="display:none;" href="tyyu.aspx">
                    Availability
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menulinks " style="display:none;" href="asdf.aspx">
                    Tours &amp; Packages
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="display:none;">
                <a class="menuHeader " style="display:none;" href="zxcv.aspx" aria-haspopup="true">
                    My Account
                </a>
                
                 <ul>
                     
                     <li class="menulinks subItem" style="display:none;">
                      <a class="menulinks subItem " style="display:none;" href="qazx.aspx">
                          User Accounts</a>
                     </li>
                     
                 </ul>
              
             </li>
      
             <li style="">
                <a class="menulinks " style="" href="URL target="_blank">
                    Portfolio
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
             <li style="">
                <a class="menulinks " style="" href="**UNIQUE VARIABLE TARGET**" target="_blank">
                    Rates &amp; info
                </a>
                
             </li>
      
</ul>
```

The unique variable needs to be placed in the final menu item, however it's sitting in div class elsewhere.. The variable resource shows up in H1 but I am simply unable to move it to the menu item. The problem is that each resource is linked to a specific user specific file, so any changes would need to be done in that file. Here is an example of the separate files:

```
        <h1 class="title">Download your confidential STO Rates</h1><a href="unique url">Rates and Information</a>
```

The header of the document links back to our SQL server, where each user is assigned a specific code.

What I would like is one of the two:

1.) Since the variables are that the URL displayed in these files in H1 currently could be one of 5, what JS can I use to retrieve a URL in another div and post it to the menu item? The resources are URL's going to another resource and only have 5 different endings #. I"m assuming it's an onlick event but I'm not very good at JS to be honest and uncertain.

2.) Alternatively, I can output try to configure the separate client files to be part of the menu item ideally, but I'm not certain how to do this.

Again, I'm very new at this so any advice would be really helpful. Post COVID our industry has forced us to learn things we normally wouldn't have during the normal course of events!

Thanks so much

-

Comment: If it's important, that the users can't see the content purposed to other users, you should use server-side authorization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. There is server side authorization, which by extension sits in the separate H1 files. It may just be a styling or other basic java issue that's not occurring to me on the front end.